# Missing Records w/ Nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been working on this qry for running enrollment reports.  It counts how many students are enrolled in each class but where classes do not have enrollments yet, the courses do not pull into the report at all. I would like the report to show all courses include those with a current enrollment of zero.

I compared the results with an old Brio Query that we are migrating away from and that qry shows courses with zero enrollments.  I migrated that qry (designer view) into the code below for use with TOAD but I am missing those courses.  The joins are identical to the old qry.

Please let me know what is incorrect about this if possible.
Thank you

```
select
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE Term_Code,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE Part_of_Term,
    SSRXLST.SSRXLST_XLST_GROUP XList,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN CRN,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE || ' ' || SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB Course_Number,
    SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_TITLE as "Title",
    count(distinct (SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_PIDM)) Enrollment
from
    SATURN.SSBSECT
    inner join SATURN.SCBCRSE on (
        SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE
        and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB = SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB
    )
    left join SATURN.SFRSTCR on (
        SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE
        and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN = SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_CRN
    )
    left join SATURN.SSRXLST on (
        SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = SSRXLST.SSRXLST_TERM_CODE
        and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN = SSRXLST.SSRXLST_CRN
    )
where
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE = '202102'
    and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_COLL_CODE = 'SU'
    and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM = (
        select
            max(scbcrse_eff_term)
        from
            saturn.scbcrse xppd
        where
            xppd.scbcrse_subj_code = scbcrse.scbcrse_subj_code
            and xppd.scbcrse_crse_numb = scbcrse.scbcrse_crse_numb
            and xppd.scbcrse_eff_term <= ssbsect_term_code
    )
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE in ('A', 'E', 'O')
    and SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE in ('RE', 'RW')
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE in ('H5A', 'H5B', 'HSL', 'H10', 'HND')
    and SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB <> '0'
    and SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB like '%E'
group by
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_TERM_CODE,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE,
    SSRXLST.SSRXLST_XLST_GROUP,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRN,
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE || ' ' || SSBSECT.SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB,
    SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_TITLE
order by
    SSBSECT.SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE,
    SCBCRSE.SCBCRSE_TITLE,
    SSRXLST.SSRXLST_XLST_GROUP 
--order by Enrollment desc
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to preserve the "outer" character of your joins, you shouldn't have references to columns from the outer-joined tables in the `where` clause.

In your code, you left-outer-join to the table aliased as `SFRSTCR` Then you have a condition on `SFRSTCR.SFRSTCR_RSTS_CODE` in the `where` clause; the "extra rows" created by the outer join will have `null` in that column, so the condition in the `where` clause will filter those rows out.

Instead, exactly the same condition should be moved to the `on` clause of the left-outer-join, with the other conditions on `SFRSTCR`.

I didn't spot any other similar situations (other than that specific one); if you still don't get the desired result after you make the change I suggested, look for more occurrences of the same.